# When finding the basic solutions to a given system of equations do I put it in REF or RREF?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've recently been doing this textbook for my course and one of the questions stumped me a bit. I found the basic solutions to the following system, here is the question:

[image: textbook problem]

From here I performed the following:

[image: my work]

But yet, when checking with Slader I arrived at the wrong answer somehow? Was I supposed to REF?? But the textbook says to RREF (Reference here):

[image]

Am I going crazy? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: First of all you have the wrong coefficient matrix at the very beginning.

Comment: @vb628 yikes I do... That could be why my answer is different

Comment: Yep that should (hopefully) clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go all the way to RREF or not, as long as you back substitute correctly.   You or the author must have made a mistake somewhere.

The amount of work will wind up being about the same.   A careless mistake is easy to make.

The difference is whether you clear out and get all zeros above each pivot.

Now, having checked your work, I noticed you started off with a mistake in the second coefficient on the first row.   It should be a  $2$, not a $1$.  Not sure if there's more than one mistake.